# jQuery, Variables and Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've read that accessing objects or collections via jQuery through variables is far more efficient than repeatedly accessing them via inline code.  Even in a simple test, this does appear to be true:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
        <script>
        var SomeChoiceRadios;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            SomeChoiceRadios = $("#MyForm input:radio[name='SomeChoice']");
        });

        function DoStuff()
        {
            console.profile('Optimized'); 

            for (i=0; i < 10000; i++)
                foo = SomeChoiceRadios.filter(":checked").val();

            console.profileEnd(); 
        }

        function DoStuff2()
        {
            console.profile('Inline'); 

            for (i=0; i < 10000; i++)
                foo = $("#MyForm input:radio[name='SomeChoice']:checked").val();

            console.profileEnd(); 
        }
        </script>

        <form id="MyForm" name="MyForm">
        <input type="radio" name="SomeChoice" value="0">0<br>
        <input type="radio" name="SomeChoice" value="1">1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="SomeChoice" value="2">2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="SomeChoice" value="3">3<br>
        <input type="radio" name="SomeChoice" value="4">4<br>
        <input type="radio" name="SomeChoice" value="5">5<br>
        <input type="button" value="Time" onclick="DoStuff()">
        <input type="button" value="Time" onclick="DoStuff2()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Given the above example, is there any faster way to get the value of the **`SomeChoice`** checked radio button, if I'm trying to access it using the variable (i.e. **`SomeChoiceRadios`**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks pretty good to me.  The cases where you would actually notice a performance hit lie mostly on the edge.  You could spend hours trying to improve your jQuery and not even tell the difference from the browser.

I am a big fan of variables though because it does make the code more maintainable as well as being more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for the vote of confidence.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this won't hold true for larger selected sets, but this appears to work even more quickly than your optimized version.  [See the modified demo here ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/Zkg7Z/)

```
function DoStuff3() {
    console.profile('ReallyOptimized');

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        $.each(SomeChoiceRadios, function() {
            if (this.checked) foo = this.value;
        });
    }

    console.profileEnd();
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, each() is going to run slowly for large data sets, right?

Comment: It seems to maintain performance over a much larger set: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/Zkg7Z/2/ (warning, that page will take awhile to load).